# Use DataTrigger to hide/show WPF TreeView ContectMenu

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView in my WPF application and I want to show or hide the context menu depending on the type of the treeviewItem. TreeView is databound and populated using a HierarchicalDataTemplate. I can disable the context menu items in code in the rightmouse event.
But I want this to be done in XAML instead. What I tried is;

```
<Grid.Resources>
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
   <MenuItem Name="Menu1" Header="Add " Click="AddNew_Click" ></MenuItem>
   <MenuItem Name="Menu2" Header="" Click="Menu2_Click"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
</Grid.Resources>
```

In side the Treeview I have this code

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Document.DocumentType}" Value="P">
             <Setter TargetName="icon"  Property="Source" Value="../Images/P.png"/>
             *<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"/>*

       </DataTrigger>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
```

But this gives runtime error 'object reference not set to an instance of object'. You can see the image is set with data trigger when DocumentType is 'P' and I want the context menu to be visible/enabled only when DocumentType is 'P' and hide/disabled otherwise.
Can this be done?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is Trigger not working? OR crash coming is the problem? And what value is null?

Comment: Trigger is working, the icon image gets applied.But when I try to right click on the treeviewitem to get the context menu, it gives that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another person had the same issue and he had gotten this answer from Microsoft forum. It doesn't use triggers, however the context is dynamic. I can use a variation of this to show my context menu only when I need it to depending on the bound data.

[here is the link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f9a3efc-c8d5-475c-892c-78d7b164fe9c/create-custom-tree-view-with-a-dynamic-context-menu-c-wpf?forum=wpf)

I will mark this as answered, so it might help someone in the future.